# Cookies get lost after reverse proxy set in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cookies, proxy

Cookies get lost when requests are proxied to a port, being listened by nodejs.
The proxy is set in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com:5000/ [P]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:5000/$1 [P]
```

The cookies received in requests look like an empty object:

```
cookies: [Object: null prototype] {},
```

If I send requests directly to example.com:5000, cookies are received ok.

Please advise what can be a cause of this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely need to set `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` to inform mod_proxy how to rewrite the `Set-Cookie` header, otherwise, it's going to contain the wrong host (port) and the browser will fail to set it.

This can only be configured in the main server config / VirtualHost (not `.htaccess`).

For example:

```
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "example.com:5000" "example.com"
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreversecookiedomain

Comment: Thanks, MrWhite. I'll try to make it. Is there any way to set something similar through .htaccess?

Comment: @Daniil No, unfortunately. You can't actually configure anything about the reverse proxy itself in `.htaccess`, except for the `P` flag (mod_rewrite) which sends the request through mod_proxy (which has already been configured in the server config).

Comment: I was thinking if i can put a rule in .htaccess to rewrite cookies with flag [CO]. So, basically the idea is to take the cookies from original request and pass it as it is to proxied request. I'm not sure how it will work together with [P]. I'll need to test.